# Why does weight affect acceleration with gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but my question is different, because it can't be answered with some formulae. My question is, **why** do heavier objects decelerate faster when moving away from the earth?

Comment: Are you asking why we assume [*inertial mass* and *gravitational mass*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass#Inertial_vs._gravitational_mass) are the same?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I have never heard of inertial mass before, and that could be the source of my confusion

Answer (score 3):

You ask

> why do heavier objects decelerate faster when moving away from the earth

That question can't really be answered, because they don't.

The force of gravity is a function of the distance - this is the famous inverse square law. But the force is proportional to the mass of the object - so objects with twice the mass experience twice the force. That property of mass is known as the *gravitational mass*.

But we know that $F=ma$, so if the force doubles and the mass doubles, the acceleration is the same. The mass we use in this equation is the *inertial mass*: it is the property that says "how hard to you have to push to make this thing accelerate".

As far as we have been able to tell, inertial and gravitational mass are equivalent.

This is why we can talk about $g$, the acceleration of gravity on earth - all objects experience the same acceleration. When you move away from the earth, that acceleration will be less - but it is less *by the same degree* regardless of the mass of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Objects accelerate at the same rate under the force of gravity. The force of gravity Is dependent on the mass of an object and because the acceleration of an object is proportional to the force and mass, the acceleration is the same regardless of the mass of your object.
$$
F_G=GMm/r^2
$$
$$
F=ma
$$
$$
a=F/m
$$
$$
a_G=F_G/m=GM/r^2
$$